# Notifications from a website I don't visit on my desktop

Tags: 18.04, notification

From time to time I'm getting notifications on my desktop from a website I never entered since I started using Ubuntu. Does anyone know how to fix it?

The website I'm getting the notifications from is "Tokyo Otaku Mode". Here is a picture to explain:

[image]

Comment: Check plugins and extension installation on the browser

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen I don't have something different or unusual: OpenH264 Video Codec provided by Cisco Systems, Inc, Widevine Content Decryption Module provided by Google Inc, Shockwave Flash, taper monkey, stylish, yomi-chan (translate jp words), adblock pluse, rajiko (unblock some jp radio site), and to google translate

Comment: Have you checked you Ubuntu notification settings in settings window?

Comment: sorry for the stupid question but what should I check there?

Comment: Which web browser do you use?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are using Google Chrome, then go to

```
chrome://settings/content/notifications?search=notification
```

> [image: Chrome Notifications]

and block unwanted notifications.

---

For Firefox ESR go to *Preferences → Content* or

```
about:preferences#content
```

then click *Choose*

> [image: Firefox Notifications]

and switch unwanted site to *Block* then *Save Changes*.

---

For Firefox Quantum go to *Preferences → Privacy & Security* then near *Notifications* click *Preferences* button and manage them

> [image: Firefox Quantum]

Comment: thank you very much, I did it and I hope I'll not see those messages even again
thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. It is very similar with Firefox too, preference and then I search for notifications. Then I did find the website that was bugging me.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't Stylish have some problems in terms of being an invasive app? Why yes it did, so I'd remove Stylish pronto, if I were you! For [reference](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2018/07/stylish-extension-with-2m-downloads-banished-for-tracking-every-site-visit/)