# Getting notifications from closed website (Chromium)

Tags: chromium, notification

I am currently getting notifications from a website I visited several days ago (I am realizing now that the website is not one that I should have visited to begin with, but here we are). Here is a screengrab (the x2convert is the website in question):
[image]

I have looked at this answer: [Notifications from a website I don't visit on my desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1067597/notifications-from-a-website-i-dont-visit-on-my-desktop) but I don't think I saw anything in Chromium's settings regarding this page. Is it possible that this is due to a downloaded file on my computer, or is this something coming from the browser that I simply missed?

Thanks very much for your time.

Comment: are you using their product as a browswer add-on?

Comment: @WU-TANG Not to my knowledge

Comment: I noticed there were some cookies from the site saved; I cleared those. Maybe that could help?

Comment: worth a try... you could clear ALL of your cookies if it's not much of an inconvenience. you could always use the nuclear option and purge the browser from the system and then reinstall it.... save your bookmarks though!............ i am only saying that because I am assuming that you tried those options on the link you provided.

Comment: Open your settings, type 'notifications' in the search, find the option in "Permissions", and see if the site is in there with 'allow' permissions. If it is, click the line of three dots and remove it. If it isn't, and you don't care, you can choose the option of disabling all notifications.

Comment: Have you tried ClamAV?

Answer (score 0):

Try what KGIII said. If you don't want this to happen again, then just disable browser notifications and never allow a website to get notification permissions again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Please don't add "comments" as an answer. Thank you :)